# Magento 2.3.1 Merge products from one database to another?

Tags: magento2, database, data-migration

I have a staging and a production server for my Magento 2.3.1 project. The two databases have different data and configurations, so I can not just dump the mysql db and restore it.

Is there a way to merge only products data from one database to another?

Comment: You can use Default Magento Product export, import.

Comment: @Ranganathan Thanks, this is actually a working solution. if you add this to Anwser. I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Magento's default export and import option to merge products from one magento setup to another magento:

> Admin->System->Data Transfer->Import/Export